# What is int 10 doing in assembly?

Tags: assembly, interrupt, dos, masm, x86-16

I'm trying to learn assembly for school and there is this part at the beginning of the example code:

```
mov al, 0
mov ah, 5
int 10
```

Before this there is a procedure :

```
.386
instructions SEGMENT use16
        ASSUME  CS:instructions

interrupt_handler PROC
; some code
interrupt_handler ENDP
```

What is the `int 10` line doing? Is it calling the `interrupt_handler` procedure? Why is it exactly 10?

This is all running in DoSBox and is assembled using masm.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found what appears to be a complete copy of the code in the OPs native language (Polish). https://ideone.com/fork/YQG7y . There is this section of code (run through Google translate):

```
; ================================================= =======

; main program - installation and uninstallation of the procedure
; interrupt handling

; determining page number 0 for text mode
start:
mov al, 0
mov ah, 5
int 10
```

It is clear from this code that it is a bug. It should be [`int 10h`](http://ctyme.com/intr/rb-0091.htm) and not [`int 10`](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-0048.htm) (same as `int 0ah`). `int 10h` is documented as:

> ```
> VIDEO - SELECT ACTIVE DISPLAY PAGE
> AH = 05h
> AL = new page number (00h to number of pages - 1) (see #00010)
>
> Return:
> Nothing
>
> Desc: Specify which of possibly multiple display pages will be visible
> ```

`int 10` is something completely different:

> ```
> IRQ2 - LPT2 (PC), VERTICAL RETRACE INTERRUPT (EGA,VGA)
> ```

Calling IRQ2 interrupt handler with `int 10` will effectively do nothing from the standpoint of the program. Since the default text page is likely already 0 the program works as expected.

---

The correct code:

```
mov al, 0
mov ah, 5
int 10h
```

would set the text mode display page to 0 using the BIOS service 10h function 5.

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer is `int 10h` (I think your code has a typo) typically calls a real mode interrupt handler at the vector that provides video services. [`int 10h` services](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/int-10.htm) include setting the video mode, character and string output, and graphics primitives (reading and writing pixels in graphics mode).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Do you any websites that go into more detail about this? It's still quite confusing for me (e.g. what does setting up an interrupt handler at a vector mean).

Comment: @WojtekWencel yes you can see the details in Wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INT_10H , lists of all intterupt in DOS http://www.ablmcc.edu.hk/~scy/CIT/8086_bios_and_dos_interrupts.htm

Comment: Details about interrupt vector https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interrupt_vector_table

Comment: But the wiki page is about INT 10H, not INT 10. I was confused by this at the beginning since all pages I found referred to 10H, but this program runs and works as intended so this is not a typo.

Comment: yeah, overall `int 10` is set video graphic mode http://stanislavs.org/helppc/int_10.html , you can assemble this intterupt using hex mode as `10h` , example `mov al, 13h; mov ah, 0; int 10h`

Comment: `h` i guess is suffix for hexadecimal, `int 10` and `int 10h` is same i think

Comment: What do you mean it's the same? Isn't 10h = 16

Comment: i mean is same for set up to graphic mode.. you can assemble with `int 10h`

Comment: `int 10h` doesn't *set up* an interrupt handler, it *invokes* / calls one the BIOS already set up.